# Android Thread issue (The thread runs in background)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, dialog

**Hey guys**
The problem I have today is about **Threads** , in an Android activity, I want to show a dialog with a message, icon and a title and three buttons (positive, negative and neutral), I already did that with no errors (plus the listeners and all that), I execute properly and again with no errors, the problem is in this :

```
    alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface i, int j)
        {

            pb.setVisibility(0); //pb is a progress bar
            new Thread (new Runnable ()
            {
                public void run ()
                {
                    try {
                        tv.setText("Saved!");
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        tv.setText(null);  //tv is a text view
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        finish();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        alerttmp.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                        alerttmp.setTitle("Error");
                        alerttmp.setMessage("Thread could not be executed Thread id: 100390");
                        alerttmp.show();
                    }

                }
            }).run();
        }
    });
```

See, the positive button is highlighted and stays highlighted until the activity is closed while I want the dialog to disappear, the pb to show, the tv to have the text "Saved!!" in it, then have no text in it and after all that kill the activity.

SOS guys! And thanks!

**ps:** English is not my native language so no Shakespearean words please! :) Please make the language as simple as possible! Thank you!

Comment: I also ran it on the UIThread , didn't work, until I select an answer it probably is still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't do your UI stuff in the UI thread.

You need to post runnable objects to the UI handler, and not just spawn a new thread for that.

You can use `new Handler().postDelayed(Runnable runnable, long millis)` to accomplish that.
This must be run from the UI thread of course - not from any other thread you spawn.

Comment: How do I use that ? Thanks !

Comment: I've putted my Runnable in that Handler with 5000 as a millis but didn't work

Comment: Although the dialog is gone now, the tv text is not changed all it does is to wait for about 10 seconds and then exit (with the pb running) all I need now is to make that tv's text change twice

Comment: Is your TextView actually showing (without all those changes - just static text)? Also, notice my edit - I hope that you run new Handler().postDelayed from inside the UI thread.

Comment: It works now thank you, and I saw your other comment and the timing is not a big issue just that the code works is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it using two handlers, here is the code : 
note : I'll still need to know more about handlers and the postDelayed method so a comment will help and will be sure appreciated else I'll google it up (going to do that anyway)

```
    alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface i, int j)
        {
            pb.setVisibility(0);
            tv.setText("Saved!");
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText(null);
        }}, 5000);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            finish();
}}, 5000);
        }});
```

Comment: According to your question, looks like you wanted finish() to be called 5 secs after removing the text - in that case, you need to post the 2nd runnable from inside the first runnable. (OR: just change the 2nd delay to 10secs if your timing is exact).